# why is user!.displayName.toString();e returning null when signed in to google account?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-signin

So I want to display the name of the person who is chatting in my messaging app. The name should be their google account display name. but when I pass in user!.displayName.toString(); it leaves the authors name blank. I am sure that everything else works because if I make the "name" variable any other value it works.

Here is my Login code

````
import 'package:messaging_app/myHomePage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  const Login({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Login")),
      body: GoogleLoginApp()
    );
  }
}

class GoogleLoginApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const GoogleLoginApp({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GoogleLoginAppState createState() => _GoogleLoginAppState();
}
class _GoogleLoginAppState extends State<GoogleLoginApp> {
  String name="";
  TextEditingController controller=TextEditingController();

  
  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email']);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    GoogleSignInAccount? user = _googleSignIn.currentUser;
    void click(){
      name=user!.displayName.toString();
      Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> MyHomePage(name)));
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Google Demo (Logged ' + (user == null ? 'out' : 'in') + ')'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(child: Text('Sign In'),
              onPressed: user != null ? null : () async {
                await _googleSignIn.signIn();
                setState(() {});
                click();
              }),

              ElevatedButton(child: Text('Sign Out'),
              onPressed: user == null ? null : () async {
                await _googleSignIn.signOut();
                setState(() {});
              }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }```
````

Comment: FYI, it's not possible for `user!.displayName.toString()` to be `null`.  You're probably observing it to be the empty string, which is different.

Comment: So how would I fix that?

Comment: I'm not personally familiar with `GoogleSignIn`.  I think that you should debug it yourself and first figure out where the empty string is coming from.  For example, is your `click` function being called?  What is the value of `name` when `click` assigns it?

Comment: The value of name is an empty string when I assign it and click is being called.